# calculate percentage in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

okay so I am doing this in code and I'm wondering if it would be better to do it in the database.

```
SELECT sum(x) as x, sum(y) as y, sum(z) as z from tblRWNPSStat
```

what i want to do is take the total of all the numbers

```
total=x+y+z
```

and then get the percentage of each on those variables(x,y,z)
so pretty much

```
x/total*100
y/total*100
z/total*100
```

Is it possible to do this in a stored procedure? or should I just stick to code?
P.s. I'm using sqlserver express r2 so solutions in T-sql please

Comment: yes it can be done in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create a Stored Procedure using

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PERCENTAGE 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @TOTAL decimal(10,2);
SET @TOTAL = (SELECT SUM(x) + SUM(y) + SUM(z) FROM tblRWNPSStat);
SELECT 
100* SUM(x)/@TOTAL AS [X %], 
100* SUM(y)/@TOTAL AS [Y %], 
100* SUM(z)/@TOTAL AS [Z %], 
@TOTAL AS [TOTAL] FROM 
tblRWNPSStat
END
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes it can be done in a SP but You don't need it:

```
SELECT SUM(X) as X, 
       CAST(SUM(X) AS FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(X+Y+Z) AS FLOAT ) *100 as Per_X,     
       SUM(Y) as Y, 
       CAST(SUM(Y) AS FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(X+Y+Z) AS FLOAT ) *100 as Per_Y, 
       SUM(Z) as Z, 
        CAST(SUM(Z) AS FLOAT)/CAST(SUM(X+Y+Z) AS FLOAT ) *100 as Per_Z
FROM tblRWNPSStat A
```

check out the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4be82/18)

Comment: Thank, but i really needed a stored procedure as the question I asked was only for part of my problem. Your solution works too but was just not right for my particular use case :)

Comment: no problem :), you could had created a SP with this query as well though, anyways if you feel this answer was useful you can upvote so other users can use it as a reference.